# UI Router and Rails: Template is Missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am creating an application with Rails and Angular. I am using `ui.router`. When I visit a route via a `ui-sref` link, it loads. However, if I refresh that page, I get the following error:

```
Missing template posts/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.
```

The home page (root of the site) does not have this problem. Also, if I type in a url, say /posts/1, I will get the same message, but if I click a `ui-sref` link for that post, the page will load. (Though refreshing that page will break it.) Another behavior that might shed light on the misconfiguration is that I can click a `ui-sref` link to get to the route /login – this route is undefined on the rails side, but defined in my angular routes (app.js). However, when I try to reach /login by any other means, or if I refresh /login, I get the error: 'No route matches [GET] "/login"'

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]
  root to: 'application#angular'

  resources :posts, only: [:create, :index, :show, :update, :destroy] do
    resources :comments, only: [:show, :create] do
      member do
        put '/upvote' => 'comments#upvote'
        put '/downvote' => 'comments#downvote'
      end
    end

    member do
      put '/upvote' => 'posts#upvote'
      put '/downvote' => 'posts#downvote'
    end
  end

  resources :users, only: [:show], to: 'users#show', via: 'get', layout: false
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  respond_to :json, :html

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def angular
    render 'layouts/application'
  end

  private
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        respond_with Post.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

app.js

```
angular.module('appName', ['ui.router', 'templates', 'Devise', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularMoment'])
.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  '$locationProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
          postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
            return posts.getAll();
          }]
        }
      })
      .state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'posts/_posts.html',
         controller: 'PostsCtrl',
        resolve: {
          post: ['$stateParams', 'posts', function($stateParams, posts) {
            return posts.get($stateParams.id);
          }]
        }
      })
      //more stuff here
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'auth/_login.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl',
        onEnter: ['$state', 'Auth', function($state, Auth) {
          Auth.currentUser().then(function (){
            $state.go('home');
          })
        }]
      })
      .state('register', {
        url: '/register',
        templateUrl: 'auth/_register.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl',
        onEnter: ['$state', 'Auth', function($state, Auth) {
          Auth.currentUser().then(function (){
            $state.go('home');
          })
        }]
      });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home')
}])
```

posts.rb (factory)

```
angular.module('appName')
  .factory('posts', [
    '$http',
    function($http){
    var o = {
      posts: [],
    };

    o.get = function(id) {
      return $http.get('/posts/' + id + '.json').then(function(res){
        return res.data;
      });

    return o;
  }])
```

My guess is that something needs to be changed in the configuration on the Angular side.